# Dask - Create empty array to fill and save it

Tags: python, dask

I want to **create a huge (>100GB) dask array** and then **fill it with values** that I compute. Then I want to save it as an hdf5 file. I have chosen  This is my code:

```
import dask.array as da

size = 100000
chunks = 50000
file_path = "..."

# calculate entries
A = da.zeros(shape=(size, size), chunks=(chunks, chunks))
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        A[i,j] = compute_value(i,j)

# store in FS
f = h5py.File(file_path)
dset = f.create_dataset('/data', shape=A.shape, chunks=(chunks, chunks), dtype='f8')
da.store(A, dset)
```

I get the error at the assignment A[i,j]:

```
NotImplementedError: Item assignment with <class 'tuple'> not supported
```

Note that this array is **too big to fit into RAM**. Therefore it should somehow save the array as all zeros and then update this saved matrix with the computed values. 
What is the proper way of doing this in dask?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked saving the matrix first in the hdf5 format and then changing the values. Here's the code:

```
size = 100000
chunks = 5000
file_path = "..."

A = da.zeros(shape=(size, size), chunks=(chunks, chunks))
with h5py.File(file_path, 'w') as f:
    dset = f.create_dataset('/data', shape=A.shape, chunks=(chunks, chunks), dtype='f8')
    da.store(A, dset)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            dset[i,j] = random.randint(0,101)
```

This can be loaded and used later, e.g. as follows:

```
with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as f:
    A = da.from_array(f["/data"], chunks=(chunks, chunks))
    x = da.linalg.solve(A, b)
    res = x.compute()
```